# Cant add more than 1 value to a dynamically created array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a  dynamically increasing array in C, but for some reason I cant assign values to anything but the first element of the array. When the code is running, the value of temp keeps changing, but the contents of val is just an address and the value of the first float in the list. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
//Initialise variables.
char buf[20]={0};
float temp=0;
int i=0;

//Create the initial array.
size_t size = sizeof(float)*10;
float* val = malloc(size);
if (val == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Initial malloc failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

//Open the file (a list of floats).
FILE *file;
file = fopen("/Users/cc756/Dropbox/C_ECG_PROJECT/ECG_Project/ECG_Project/dataStream", "r");

if (!file){
    printf("Coulding find file.\n");
    exit(1);
}

//Save the contents of the list to a float array.
while (fgets(buf,20, file)!=NULL){
    temp = atof(buf);
    if (temp != 0){
        val[i] = temp;
        i++;
        if(i==size){
            size *= 2;
            float* val_temp = realloc(val,size);
            if(val_temp == NULL){
                printf("Realloc failed.\n");
            }
            else{
                val = val_temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `buf` in your code? A `char*`?

Comment: You haven't initialized `i` anywhere that I can see...

Comment: Please read on how to create [mcve]. Your code is not *minimal*, because you could remove all file operations and demonstrate the problem with simple loop. It's also not *complete* as it will throw compilation errors if anyone tries to compile it as is.

Comment: @JeffLoughlin no initialization for temp and buf, too

Comment: @izlin - True...but I'm assuming `buf` points to an array, and `temp` gets a value the first time through the loop, but the OP is assuming `i` to be 0 the first time through - disatrous if it's not.

Comment: Sorry, I did initialise i and buf is a char that contains the data from the list!

Comment: The problem I'm having is that when I try to assign values to val[2] val[3] etc they dont assign, it just shows the first element.

Comment: How are you checking values? Could you show file content?

Comment: @ChrisCollins: How are you determining that `val[2]` and `val[3]` aren't getting assigned?  Debugger?  `printf`?

Comment: @JohnBode The debugger in xcode, usually I can see all elements of an array in a drop down menu but it only shows the one.

Comment: @ChrisCollins: I'm not that familiar with `xcode`.  Remember that `val` is a pointer, not an array - perhaps you need to set something in `xcode` to view the elements past `val`.  Also try printing out your array elements with `printf`.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/5tua9k/9 here is a link to what I see in the xcode

Comment: I think I'm trying to assign values to a pointer.. maybe my syntax is wrong? But I cant compile unless I have it like that because I get build errors.

Comment: @ChrisCollins - The Xcode debugger isn't very smart when it comes to arrays and pointers - the debugger is only showing you the first value because it thinks val is just a pointer to int (which it is)

Comment: @JohnBode when I try to print even the first value nothing comes out.

Comment: You need to show us the actual code then, including the printfs you are using to debug.  See @user694733's comment above

Comment: Should I use linked lists or some other method? I'm not sure what the best way to do this is... I just want an array whos size increases as I add more values as I will be recieving data from a stream.

Comment: add `for(int i=0; i<5; i++) printf("val[%d]=%f\n", i, val[i]);` after your while and tell us what is the output.

Comment: Have you got blank lines between values, as shown in link?

Comment: I get a malloc error. I just realied that val[i] contains a memory address, not the actual value? *val contains the float but if I use *val[i] I get a build error saying I cannot use this referencing for a float.

Comment: @LPs Sorry in that link I had removed the realloc part... And yes, thast why I have an if statement to ignore '0' values, they were already in my data before I got hold of it.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/15688 <= full code (edited)

Comment: Your code, with fix proposed by Vlad in its answer, works well. Your problem is with your debugger. Add the loop I commented, you'll see right values for first 5 positions

Comment: @LPs Seriously? So the debugger is making me think im crazy and taking me 5 hours to sort? :(

Comment: Did you try the `printf` loop?

Comment: Just tried and got it to print, but the code has to be running to see it (im used to matlab and didnt realise that). Ok so its working now, thanks a lot!!! Is there any way to see the array rather than just the first value?

Comment: You should post another question with specific description, at least with [tag:xcode] tag

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean

```
if ( i == size / sizeof( float ) ){
```

Also the logic of the loop

```
while (fgets(buf,20, file)!=NULL){
    temp = atof(buf);
    if (temp != 0){
        val[i] = temp;
        i++;
        if(i==size){
            size *= 2;
            float* val_temp = realloc(val,size);
            if(val_temp == NULL){
                printf("Realloc failed.\n");
            }
            else{
                val = val_temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is wrong in case when `val_temp` will be assigned `NULL` because `i` was increased and in the next iteration of the loop this statement

```
val[i] = temp;
```

results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things...

Life will be a lot simpler if you use `size` to just track the *number of elements* in the array, rather than the byte size of the array.  Trust me.

```
size_t size = 10;
float *val = malloc( size * sizeof *val );
```

Also, don't update the value of `size` until after you're sure the `realloc` call succeeded:

```
if ( i == size )
{
  float *val_temp = realloc( val, (size * 2) * sizeof *val );
  if ( val_temp )
  {
    size *= 2;
    val = val_temp;
  }
  else
  {
    // handle realloc failure
  }
}
```

Why?  You may decide that a `realloc` failure is not fatal and return what you've read so far - in that case, you want `size` to accurately reflect what you have.

As for troubleshooting your current problem, I suggest adding some debug `printf` statements:

```
while( ... )
{
  ...
  fprintf( stderr, "i = %d\n", i );
  fprintf( stderr, "size = %zu\n", size );
  fprintf( stderr, "val = %p\n", (void *) val );
  fprintf( stderr, "val[%d] = %f\n\n", i, val[i] ); 
  ...
}
```

That way you can see exactly what you have on each iteration of the loop.